# Have any jurisdictions made a large number of prosecutions for FGM?

Tags: human-rights, rule-of-law

Many governments publicly take actions that appear to oppose female genital mutilation, such as passing laws against doing it in their own jurisdiction, forbidding people from going to another jurisdiction and doing it there, running awareness campaigns, and setting up guidelines for reporting cases of FGM.

In many jurisdictions I'm aware of, there either hasn't been any prosecutions, or they're in the low single digits, often with news of a prosecution noting that it's the first one. However, I am biased in what jurisdictions I know about. Is the lack of prosecutions a world-wide situation, or are there countries with hundreds if not more prosecutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to various (somewhat inconsistent) sources, since the 1980s, there have been about one hundred people found guilty of a crime in relation with feminine genital mutilations in France, see [1](https://www.cairn.info/revue-population-2016-2-page-224.htm) and [2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilations_g%C3%A9nitales_f%C3%A9minines#Pays_occidentaux). So not hundreds or thousands but more than single digits.

More recently, most of the countries where these mutilations are most prevalent passed laws banning them but I have no idea about the degree of enforcement.

Comment: As a heads up for others, the references, while apparently high quality, are in French.